# How to use one sourceode checkout for all the Bamboo stages?

Tags: bamboo

I am planning to create 4 stages

1. Source code checkout stages
2. Build for dev env stages
3. Build for uat env stages
4. Build for Prod env stages

Is it possible to use the same source code check out for all the stages? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually straight forward:

- Define your repository in the Repository tab of the plan configuration
- Add a Sourcecode Checkout task for each build job in the plan.

By virtue of the repository definition for the plan, a consistent snapshot at the time the plan was started, will be used for the checkout tasks i.e. they will each fetch the same code.

This is not clearly documented in the Bamboo docs but is discussed here https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/33651/stages-and-artifact-passing

Answer (score 1):

Above answer works, but I think you should not build same branch with all environments. It might be better to use better branching workflow,so that you can easily deploy correct change to required environment.